# Computing Algol's apparent magnitude from TESS observation data

Tags: python, variable-star, tess

A helpful developer downloaded a light curve of Algol from STScI's MAST service of the TESS archive for me.

Its content looks like this:

```
# Time (BTJD),Normalized SAP_FLUX,Normalized SAP_BKG
1791.7659704711036,0.9953357713196904,0.20449268441018317
1791.7868043033843,0.9966320680638372,0.20297345806471756
1791.8076381341903,0.9975026399246625,0.20580296858683853
1791.828471963651,0.9983619224857635,0.20546566683189757
1791.8493057916578,0.9992328214823062,0.20573661958168665
```

He told me I could calculate the magnitude in the following way

```
import juliandate
import datetime
import numpy as np

def get_algol_magnitude(date): # python datetime
    # read data from the text file
    data = np.genfromtxt('hlsp_qlp_tess_ffi_s0018-0000000346783960_tess_v01_llc.txt', delimiter=',')

    tess_start_date = 2457000.0
    tess_algol_mag = 3.3684
    
    # calculate Julian Date and BTJD offset
    jd = juliandate.from_gregorian(date.year,date.month,date.day,date.hour,date.minute,date.second)
    btjd_offset = jd - tess_start_date

    # find index of closest time to datetime_obj
    index = np.absolute(data[0] - btjd_offset).argmin()

    # calculate Algol magnitude
    magnitude = tess_algol_mag - 2.5 * math.log10(data[1][index])

    return magnitude
```

But he also told me this method works only work if the intended query date is in the range of the observation dates of TESS for this object. If not, I need an eclipsing binary model to predict magnitudes on arbitary dates.

There's been another helpful person who advised me how to calculate the phase of Algol for a given date.

```
def get_algol_phase(time):
     time_jd = juliandate.from_gregorian(date.year,date.month,date.day,date.hour,date.minute,date.second)
     
     epoch_minimum_jd=2460072.826389
     algol_period=2.867328

     days_from_epoch = abs(epoch minimum_jd - time_jd)
     algol_phase = (days_from_epoch / algol_period) % 1.0   
 
     return algol_phase


time = datetime.datetime.now()
algol_phase = get_algol_phase(time)
```

Well since I don't really understand this, is there a way how to combine those 2 functions/datas together so I can have a function to obtain the magnitude of Algol for any date?

Comment: These two methods do very different things.  The first looks up an observation of algol from history.  The second is (part of) a theoretical model for algol.  You need to decide: do you want to use a theoretical model?  Or do you want to use observations?  It is your choice.

Comment: I mean can I make my own theoretical model from the observation data? I would take the observation data and combine them with Algol phase. So for example - first line  BTJD 1791.7659704711036 this is JD 2458791.7659704713 and using the function I get Algol phase 0.7784705930066593 and this gives magnitude of 3.373475968909212. Than for any date whose Algol phase is close to 0.7784705930066593 I had a magnitude of 3.373475968909212...

Comment: You could but there are easier ways. Like using an existing light curve.